# access many to many relation in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called [`Tag`](https://github.com/callicoder/jpa-hibernate-tutorials/blob/master/jpa-many-to-many-demo/src/main/java/com/example/jpa/model/Tag.java):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

And a class called [`Post`](https://github.com/callicoder/jpa-hibernate-tutorials/blob/master/jpa-many-to-many-demo/src/main/java/com/example/jpa/model/Post.java)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tags",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "post_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();


        ...
}
```

It creates another table named `post_tags`.

How can I write a `Controller` to access that table as it is not similar a repository?

Is there more easy and convenient way to implement *ManyToMany* relationship ?

My [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/V0R40E5j)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access that relation table manually. You can load load all `Tag` entities, and then load all the referenced `Post` entities.

The relation table is enterily managed by your ORM frameork.

But, if you still want to access the relation table, you can use native queries in your Spring Data JPA repository, e.g.

```
@Query(value="select post_id, tag_id from post_tags", nativeQuery=true)
List<PostTag> loadPostTags();
```

`PostTag` class is not a jpa-managed entity and must match the structue of the returned table:

```
public class PostTag {
 private long postId;
 private long tagId;
 // getter, setter
}
```

Comment: Should I implement that query in `PostTagRepository`, right ?

Comment: you can put that in any existing repository

Comment: Can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258189/spring-boot-many-to-many-post-method-not-updating-data), please . Till then let me implement this ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "post_tags",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "post_id") })
   private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "post_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long postId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should I change the owning entity ?